# Working with XMLs: trying to loop through XmlNodes returns NULL values, when there are values in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have an issue with the following code:

```
    private static DataTable GetSchedule(string ServerUrl, string LocalAPIKey)
    {

        string result = "";

        // Create the web request
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(ServerUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;

        request.Method = @"POST";
        request.UserAgent = "NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "uri:xx/GetSchedule");

        string xmlPayload = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""
                            xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soapenv=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""
                            xmlns:uri=""uri:xx"">
                            <soapenv:Header/>
                            <soapenv:Body>
                            <uri:wsdlGetSchedule soapenv:encodingStyle=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"">
                            <apiKey xsi:type = ""xsd:string"">"+LocalAPIKey+@"</apiKey>
                            <GetSchedule xsi:type= ""flex:GetSchedule"" xmlns:flex= ""https://server/soap/xx"">
                            <fromDate xsi:type=""xsd:string"">2017-03-31</fromDate>
                            <toDate xsi:type=""xsd:string"">2017-03-31</toDate>
                            </GetSchedule>
                            </uri:wsdlGetSchedule>
                            </soapenv:Body>
                            </soapenv:Envelope>
        ";

        // Create the data we want to send
        StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
        data.Append(xmlPayload);
        // Create a byte array of the data we want to send
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;
        // Set the content length in the request headers
        Console.WriteLine(request.ContentLength.ToString());

        // Write data to request
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        // Get response and return it
        XmlDocument xmlResult = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(result);
                reader.Close();
            }
            xmlResult.LoadXml(result);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Schedule");
        dt.Columns.Add("Date");
        dt.Columns.Add("StartTime");
        dt.Columns.Add("EndTime");
        dt.Columns.Add("Scheduled_Hours");
        dt.Columns.Add("StoreKey");
        XmlNodeList also_calledList = xmlResult.GetElementsByTagName("return");
        XmlNode also_calledElement = also_calledList[0];
        XmlNodeList titleList = also_calledElement.ChildNodes;

        foreach (XmlNode titleNode in titleList)
        {

            if (titleNode["badgeNo"] != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Inside foreach loop");
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Date"] = titleNode["begDate"].InnerText;
                row["StartTime"] = titleNode["begTime"].InnerText;
                row["EndTime"] = titleNode["endTime"].InnerText;
                row["Scheduled_Hours"] = titleNode["hours"].InnerText;
                row["StoreKey"] = titleNode["costCentre"].InnerText;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(titleNode["begDate"].InnerText + " " + titleNode["begTime"].InnerText + " " + titleNode["endTime"].InnerText + " " + titleNode["hours"].InnerText);
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
           }
            else
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("badgeNo not found");
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

but when I inspect `titleList` using `Quick Watch -> Results View -> [0] -> First Child -> InnerXml` I get the following output:

```
<item xsi:type="tns:Schedule" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance">
<begDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</begDate>
<begTime xsi:type="xsd:time">16:00:00</begTime>
<endDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</endDate>
<endTime xsi:type="xsd:time">20:15:00</endTime>
<persId xsi:type="xsd:int">316</persId>
<badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">3334</badgeNo>
<section xsi:type="xsd:int">1</section>
<sectionName xsi:type="xsd:string">
</sectionName>
<hours xsi:type="xsd:decimal">4.25</hours>
<costCentre xsi:type="xsd:int">5697</costCentre>
</item>
```

and when I inspect `dt` it only shows the headers, but *no actual data (only "NULL")*.

How can this be? InnerXml shows records of for instance `badgeNo` which is the constraint from entering the `If statement`. Still, the text inside the if loop `"In the foreach loop"` is never executed.

Why doesn't the program go into the if loop?

> Edit

This is the file `xmlResult`. Note that some attributes are removed, since there are 50 columns which is returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:tns="https://SERVERURL">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:wsdlGetSchedulesV2Response xmlns:ns1="uri:FlexForce">
<return xsi:type="tns:SchedulesV2Response">
<schedules xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:ScheduleV2[4]">
<item xsi:type="tns:ScheduleV2">
<restId xsi:type="xsd:int">1124</restId>
<begDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</begDate>
<begTime xsi:type="xsd:time">16:00:00</begTime>
<endDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</endDate>
<endTime xsi:type="xsd:time">20:15:00</endTime>
<breakType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</breakType>
<begBreak xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak>
<endBreak xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak>
<begBreak2 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak2>
<endBreak2 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak2>
<begBreak3 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak3>
<endBreak3 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak3>
<begBreak4 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak4>
<endBreak4 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak4>
<persId xsi:type="xsd:int">345516</persId>
<badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">3334</badgeNo>
<status xsi:type="xsd:int">1</status>
<grabbAble xsi:type="xsd:int">0</grabbAble>
<grabbId xsi:type="xsd:int">0</grabbId>
<approved xsi:type="xsd:int">0</approved>
<managerId xsi:type="xsd:int">490150</managerId>
<categoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">4845</categoryId>
<categoryName xsi:type="xsd:string">Öppet skift</categoryName>
<comment xsi:type="xsd:string">
</comment>
<section xsi:type="xsd:int">1</section>
<sectionName xsi:type="xsd:string">
</sectionName>
<hours xsi:type="xsd:decimal">4.25</hours>
<fixSchedId xsi:type="xsd:int">0</fixSchedId>
<shiftChanged xsi:type="xsd:int">0</shiftChanged>
<costCentre xsi:type="xsd:int">5697</costCentre>
</item>
</schedules>
<validationErrors xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]">
</validationErrors>
</return>
</ns1:wsdlGetSchedulesV2Response>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope
```

> Edit 2

I've edited the line

```
XmlNodeList also_calledList = XmlResult.GetElementByTagName("return");
```

into

```
XmlNodeList also_calledList = XmlResult.GetElementByTagName("item");
```

This still produces an error that `badgeNo` gets an `NullException` in the `if` statement inside the loop.

The `XmlNode` has the following appearence under `Results View` ranging from `[0]` through `[50]` for each attribute. At Place number 15 I can find `badgeNo` with the following `OuterXml`:

```
<badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">3334</badgeNo>
```

so it do have a value.

If I were to have `return` instead of `item` for generating the `titleNode` (as in the original solution) I get the following InnerXml on `titleNode`:

```
<schedules xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="tns:ScheduleV2[4]" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<item xsi:type="tns:ScheduleV2">
<restId xsi:type="xsd:int">1124</restId>
<begDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</begDate>
<begTime xsi:type="xsd:time">16:00:00</begTime>
<endDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</endDate>
<endTime xsi:type="xsd:time">20:15:00</endTime>
<breakType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</breakType>
<begBreak xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak>
<endBreak xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak>
<begBreak2 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak2>
<endBreak2 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak2>
<begBreak3 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak3>
<endBreak3 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak3>
<begBreak4 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</begBreak4>
<endBreak4 xsi:type="xsd:time">00:00:00</endBreak4>
<persId xsi:type="xsd:int">345516</persId>
<badgeNo xsi:type="xsd:string">3334</badgeNo>
<status xsi:type="xsd:int">1</status>
<grabbAble xsi:type="xsd:int">0</grabbAble>
<grabbId xsi:type="xsd:int">0</grabbId>
<approved xsi:type="xsd:int">0</approved>
<managerId xsi:type="xsd:int">490150</managerId>
<categoryId xsi:type="xsd:int">4845</categoryId>
<categoryName xsi:type="xsd:string">Öppet skift</categoryName>
<comment xsi:type="xsd:string">
</comment>
<section xsi:type="xsd:int">1</section>
<sectionName xsi:type="xsd:string">
</sectionName>
<hours xsi:type="xsd:decimal">4.25</hours>
<fixSchedId xsi:type="xsd:int">0</fixSchedId>
<shiftChanged xsi:type="xsd:int">0</shiftChanged>
<costCentre xsi:type="xsd:int">5697</costCentre>
</item>
</schedules>
```

and also, `titleNode` has 2 elements then, `[0]` corresponds to every attribute found within the `item` block, and `[1]` corresponds to `validationErrors`.

Comment: Please post XML that can be parsed. Where is that `<comment>` element supposed to have started?

Comment: @EdPlunkett    Thanks for replying. The XML had many, many rows originally so I had to edit it some and that </comment> section wasn't intended to be there. I've edited the OP.

Comment: Thank you. In your C#, what's `xmlResult`?

Comment: Your loop assumes that `titleList` is a collection of `item` elements, so `titleList[0]` should itself be an `item` element, and `titleList[0].FirstChild` should be `<begDate xsi:type="xsd:date">2017-03-31</begDate>`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `if (titleNode["badgeNo"] != null)` and look at `titleNode` in the quick watch. It should be an "item", but I think it's actually the *parent* of an "item". Can I see the entire whole complete structure of your XML? I don't need every "item" element, just one or two would be ideal -- but I need to see all the parent elements up to the root of the document.

Comment: Do you want to loop through every "item" in the XML, or some subset of them?

Comment: *"I'm not sure how my test for NULL can get an error because the value is NULL...."* --  in `titleNode["badgeNo"].InnerText`, `titleNode["badgeNo"]` is null.

Comment: @EdPlunkett     Thanks for replying! I've included the whole function code, also I've written how the titleNode looks like. It seems to be identical to titleList. When I make a `Quick Watch` on titleNode, Before I expand it, it says that the value is `{Element, Name = "Schedules"}`  and the type is `System.Xml.XmlNode{System.Xml.XmlElement}`.

Comment: There are no "return" or "Schedules" elements in any of the XML you've provided, so I'm unable to help you. You may want `var titleList = xmlResult.SelectNodes("item");`, but that's just a guess, since you're unable to provide any of the information I asked for, and what you are telling me instead is contradictory.

Comment: @EdPlunkett    I'll try to find the lines you requested. I must leave work now though. Have a nice day, I edited to include OuterXML if that helps.

Comment: @EdPlunkett    I've had more time to look into this matter. I've edited the OP quite some bit. I hope that I've been able to provide the information you asked for Before the weekend.

Comment: @EdPlunkett    Now I realized what you meant! I had a structure where I had a <return><Schedule><item>, so when I tried to filter using <Schedule> it finally worked! 

Feel free to add your comments as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for help!